# How do I remove a url using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to remove/block just "ymwmzInOLwk" using .htaccess?

This is the full url I have: http://www.example.com/yt.php?v=ymwmzInOLwk

Answer (score 0):

To block that query parameter use this rule in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)v=ymwmzInOLwk(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: sorry if question wasn't clear. This blocked the entire url and I don't want that to happen. lets say there are two urls  http://www.example.com/yt.php?v=ymwmzInOLwk and  http://www.example.com/yt.php?v=fdafdfdaffda  how do you block just the first one without harming second link? if I use code you have  gave be above, it blocks all urls.

Comment: Check updated answer now. It will only block `http://www.example.com/yt.php?v=ymwmzInOLwk` now.

Comment: May I know what's wrong with the answer that you removed acceptance?